# How to align text in a file to looks like a table in bash based on pattern text?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following text

```
'   14411.7647 e0       - 2647.0588 e3       + 7352.9412 e12      + 14411.7647 e123       21828.2063'
' - 2647.0588 e3       + 7352.9412 e12        7814.9002'
'   14411.7647 e0       + 14411.7647 e123       20381.3131'
'   14411.7647 e0       + 14411.7647 e123       20381.3131'
'   0.0000 e0       + 0.0000 e123       1.9293e-12'
'   14411.7647'
```

and I'd like to align to look like a table based on the eXXX terms. This could be an example output:

```
' 14411.7647 e0     - 2647.0588 e3      + 7352.9412 e12     + 14411.7647 e123   21828.2063'                 
'                   - 2647.0588 e3      + 7352.9412 e12                          7814.9002'                 
' 14411.7647 e0                                             + 14411.7647 e123   20381.3131'                 
' 14411.7647 e0                                             + 14411.7647 e123   20381.3131'                 
'     0.0000 e0                                                 + 0.0000 e123   1.9293e-12'                 
'                                                                               14411.7647'
```

The most important part is to align the eXXX terms along with it's coefficients.

UPDATE: the columns are originally separated by spaces. The output could be separated by tabs, for example.

UPDATE2: The first row indicates the total number of columns. There are no more columns than those in the first row. The exxx in second and following rows can be the same or not than in the first row, but you'll never find more terms than the first row nor will be unordered (i.e. e12 will be after e3 always)

Can this be achieved using awk or similar?

Comment: Which character separates the columns? One tab or multiple spaces?

Comment: @Cyrus multiples spaces.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I tried several combinations to align the columns like: `sed -Ee 's/  +/\t/g'  < file.txt` and others, but cannot complete to align based on eXXX terms

Comment: multiple spaces? How do I know if in the second line the `- 2647.0588 e3` should be in the second column? Why not in the first column? Why not the fourth or third column? What is the key to sorting which field goes to which column? Are the `exx` constant within a file? Are we expected to search the whole file for all possible `eXX` fields and then decide how many columns there should be? What if `e3` field is after `e12` in one line? Should we change the order then?

Comment: I updated (UPDATE2) my question to clarify you comment @KamilCuk

Comment: Are there REALLY `'`s at the start and end of every line?

Comment: the `'` are not really a problem.. can be removed easily (begin and end of line)

Comment: None of your input is a problem, I just wanted to make sure that what you really have truly looks like the example you posted.

Comment: Is the last column guaranteed to be in all lines?

Comment: No, It might not be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks the fields can be split by multi-spaces, then you can try using FS="`*\047 *|  +`", this way, your final expected lines(based on `NR==1`) can be split into eXXX columns(from `$2` to `$(NF-2)`), a regular column if exists at `$(NF-1)`. both $1 and $NF are always EMPTY.

```
$ cat t17.1.awk
BEGIN{ FS = " *\047 *|  +"; OFS = "\t"; }

# on the first line, set up the total N = NF
# the keys and value lengths for the 'eXXX' cols 
# to sort and format fields for all rows
NR == 1 {
    N = NF
    for (i=2; i < N-1; i++) {
        n1 = split($i, a, " ")
        e_cols[i] = a[n1]
        e_lens[i] = length($i)
    }
    # the field-length of the regular column which is non eXXX-cols
    len_last = length($(NF-1))
}

{
    printf "\047 "
    # hash the e-key for field from '2' to 'NF-1'
    # include NF-1 in case the last regular column is missing
    for (i=2; i < NF; i++) {
        n1 = split($i, a, " ")
        hash[a[n1]] = $i
    }

    # print the eXXX-cols based on the order as in NR==1
    for (i=2; i < N-1; i++) {
        printf("%*s%s", e_lens[i], hash[e_cols[i]], OFS)
    }

    # print the regular column at $(NF-1) or EMPTY if it is an eXXX-cols
    printf("%*s\047\n", len_last, match($(NF-1),/ e[0-9]+$/)?"":$(NF-1))

    # reset the hash
    delete hash
}
```

Run the above script and you will get the following result: (Note, I appended one extra row so that an eXXX-cols `+ 14411.7647 e123` is at the end of the line before the trailing `'`)

```
$ awk -f t17.1.awk file.txt 
' 14411.7647 e0 - 2647.0588 e3  + 7352.9412 e12 + 14411.7647 e123       21828.2063'
'               - 2647.0588 e3  + 7352.9412 e12                          7814.9002'
' 14411.7647 e0                                 + 14411.7647 e123       20381.3131'
' 14411.7647 e0                                 + 14411.7647 e123       20381.3131'
'     0.0000 e0                                     + 0.0000 e123       1.9293e-12'
'                                                                       14411.7647'
'                                               + 14411.7647 e123                 '
```

**Note:**

- you might need **gawk** to make `"%*s"` work for `printf()`, in case it's not working, try a fixed number, for example: `printf("%18s%s", hash[e_cols[i]], OFS)`
- some of values in the e-cols might have longer size than the corresponding one at NR==1, to fix this, you can manually specify an array for lengths or just use a fixed number

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    # Get rid of all single quotes at the start/end of lines
    gsub(/^\047|\047$/,"")

    # Attach the +/- sign when present to the number to its right
    # to normalize how the fields are presented on each line.
    gsub(/\+ /,"+")
    gsub(/- /,"-")
}
NR==1 {
    # Consider each pair like "14411.7647 e0" to be one field with
    # "e0" as the key that determines the output order for that field
    # and "14411.7647" as the value associated with that key. Here
    # we create an array that remembers the order of the keys.
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        key = $(i+1)
        fldNr2key[++numFlds] = key
    }
}
{
    # Populate an array that maps the key to its value
    delete key2val
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        key = $(i+1)
        val = $i
        key2val[key] = val
    }

    # Print the values by the order of the keys
    out = ""
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
        key = fldNr2key[fldNr]
        fld = ""
        if (key in key2val) {
            val = key2val[key]
            fld = val (key ~ /./ ? " " key : "")
            sub(/^[-+]/,"& ",fld) # restore the blank after a leading +/-
        }
        out = out fld (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : "")
    }
    print "\047 " out "\047"
}
```

Tab-separated output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
' 14411.7647 e0 - 2647.0588 e3  + 7352.9412 e12 + 14411.7647 e123       21828.2063'
'       - 2647.0588 e3  + 7352.9412 e12         7814.9002'
' 14411.7647 e0                 + 14411.7647 e123       20381.3131'
' 14411.7647 e0                 + 14411.7647 e123       20381.3131'
' 0.0000 e0                     + 0.0000 e123   1.9293e-12'
'                               14411.7647'
```

Visually tabular output (or use printfs with an appropriate width for each field in the script):

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
' 14411.7647 e0  - 2647.0588 e3  + 7352.9412 e12  + 14411.7647 e123  21828.2063'
'                - 2647.0588 e3  + 7352.9412 e12                     7814.9002'
' 14411.7647 e0                                   + 14411.7647 e123  20381.3131'
' 14411.7647 e0                                   + 14411.7647 e123  20381.3131'
' 0.0000 e0                                       + 0.0000 e123      1.9293e-12'
'                                                                    14411.7647'
```

Comment: very nice and elegant solution.

Comment: thank you, it also worked in linux. Anyway, not the same result in a mac os :(

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, the `/+/` was undefined behavior per POSIX so it'd only work in some awks. I've corrected it now to `/\+/`